# CSS Grid, placing elements on different columns

Tags: css, css-grid

HI there I am struggling with this.
I have a web design like this.

```html
html {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 80% 10%;
  grid-template-rows: 10% 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
}
body {
  grid-column-start: 2
  grid-row-start: 2
}
header {
  grid-column-start: 1
  grid-row-start: 2
}
```

Here's my simple HTML code:

```html
<body>
<header>
<p>This should be on Lateral</p>
</header>
<p>this should be on the center</p>
</body>
```

[image: grid]

But I can't manage to place the `<p>` on the header to the lateral column. Help is appreciated

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The header should be inside the body

Comment: Edited, thanks @Paulie_D

Comment: I suggest you don't use grid on the html element, you might get some weird behaviors